# Errors with foreach loop on the CodeIgniter tutorial

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to work through the CodeIgniter tutorial and my news pages won't output data from the foreach loop. I get the following messages:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: news

Filename: pages/index.php

Line Number: 1
```

and

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: pages/index.php

Line Number: 1
```

This is my model class:

```
<?php
class News_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->database();
}


public function get_news($slug = FALSE)
{
if ($slug === FALSE)
{
    $query = $this->db->get('news');
    return $query->result_array();
}

$query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('slug' => $slug));
return $query->row_array();
}


public function index()
{
$data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
$data['title'] = 'News archive';

$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
$this->load->view('news/index', $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
}
```

And my controller:

```
class News extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('news_model');
}

public function index()
{
    $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
}


public function view($slug)
{
    $data['news_item'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);

    if (empty($data['news_item']))
    {
        show_404();
    }

    $data['title'] = $data['news_item']['title'];

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('news/view', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}

}
```

And the first view:

```
    <h2><?php echo $news_item['title'] ?></h2>
    <div id="main">
        <?php echo $news_item['text'] ?>
    </div>
    <p><a href="news/<?php echo $news_item['slug'] ?>">View article</a></p>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

and the second:

```
<?php
echo '<h2>'.$news_item['title'].'</h2>';
echo $news_item['text'];
```

I know there are other questions about the tutorial but none seemed to help me.

Thanks.

Comment: The  function view($slug) is defined twice in controller

Answer (score 1):

in model you have closed your class after constructor. Should be closed after all function.
Also view() is initialized twice.

Comment: Hello, thanks. I made those changes but it still doesn't work and I am getting the same errors. Thanks for your help, I will look over my code again and check for any other silly errors.